# Persisting properties of nested objects

Tags: jpa

I have a table "user" with fields name, city, state, country. And then, I have a class "User" as below:

```
class User{
   String name;
   Address address;
}
```

The Address class has following:

```
class Address{
   String city;
   String state;
   String country;
}
```

Now, how can I save the "name" field of User class and properties of Address class within same entry in "user" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark an *Address* class as *[@Embeddable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)*

> Specifies a class whose instances are stored as an intrinsic part of
>   an owning entity and share the identity of the entity. Each of the
>   persistent properties or fields of the embedded object is mapped to
>   the database table for the entity.

an example

```
@Embeddable
class Address{
   String city;
   String state;
   String country;
}
```

and than

```
class User{
   String name;
   @Embedded
   Address address;
}
```

the @Embedded annotation is not required, but makes the embeddable relationship more explicit